# What is best practice for design tables for variable information?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, best-fit

I am faced with the problem that you may have experienced it,
There is a entity with formal field and variable field, For example 
consider a Person entity that have name and family and state, depend of state
value

> if state=1 then person must fill information about Education(many
>   formal field and one to many information)

or

> if state=2 then person must fill information about Healthy(many formal
>   field and one to many information)

and etc.

During develop **may be this condition changed** and a state = 7(Insurance Information) also added that the user must filled if condition state = 7 is launched!

So what is best practice to resolve this problem and **Design tables with comfort extension and least changes and easy query**?

Note that Xml filed is hard to query(for report later by another person) and i temporarily ignored this solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three choices:

1. Think ahead of time and try to foresee all posible fields needed and compile them in your table.

Lets say we got a client's table which can be both people and corporations.

We'd do something like this in the table:

example:

```
[Client]
first_name /* person */
last_name /* person */
commercial_name /* corporation */
```

This will of course make you produce a quite big table if you handle a lot of data.

2. You could handle those "variable values" as extra tables with a foreign key referencing the main table

example:

```
[Person]
person_id
first_name /* person */
last_name /* person */

[Education_info]
person_id /* refrences Person.person_id */
.... /* info */
```

3. Wordpress style, one main table, one "meta table".

example:

```
[Person]
person_id
first_name /* person */
last_name /* person */

[Person_meta]
person_id /* references person */
key_name 
key_value
```

then you'd have truly variable metadata belonging to the person.

Hope it helps!